# Json. Get value by others known value (PHP)

Tags: php, json, object

i have this json object

```
"ok": {
"ok1" : 3,
"ok2" : 4
}
```

I will try to get ok2 by ok1..

This is my current function, but its not working.

```
echo ["ok"]["ok1"][3]->["ok2"];
```

But it doesnt print out anything

Please help! Thanks

Comment: json_decode($string,true); see the array how it comes and then print !!

Comment: its not the problem. I want to try to get ok2 by ok1. But its not working

Comment: I don't think it's a valid json

Comment: Im just giving a random one.. But u know what i mean right. I'm trying to get a value by other known value

Answer (score 1):

You **CANNOT** get `OK2` by `OK1`, because `OK2` does not belong to `OK1`. The structure of your JSON is that `OK1` and `OK2` both belong to `OK`.

So only this will work:

```
// ok1
var_dump(["ok"]["ok1"]);
// ok2
var_dump(["ok"]["ok2"]);
```

Also you seem to include the value (`["ok"]["ok1"][3]`) which is NOT going to work. Only use the keys (`["ok"]["ok1"]`).

Comment: What if i have the value ok2. and i want to find its siblings? That would not be able to happen?

Comment: You do not find siblings by value, you find it by key. See last line of my answer. In your example ok2 does not have any siblings, so I cannot answer that unless you update your question.

Comment: how do i find the key ?